# Define multiple liquibase datasources in Quarkus YAML

Tags: yaml, liquibase, quarkus

How can I define multiple datasources for the Quarkus YAML extension ?

Apperantly, it works like the following in the `application.properties` file:

```
# Liquibase configuration for the default datasource
quarkus.liquibase.schemas=DEFAULT_TEST_SCHEMA
quarkus.liquibase.change-log=db/changeLog.xml
quarkus.liquibase.migrate-at-start=true

# Liquibase configuration for the "users" datasource
quarkus.liquibase.users.schemas=USERS_TEST_SCHEMA
quarkus.liquibase.users.change-log=db/users.xml
quarkus.liquibase.users.migrate-at-start=true

# Liquibase configuration for the "inventory" datasource
quarkus.liquibase.inventory.schemas=INVENTORY_TEST_SCHEMA
quarkus.liquibase.inventory.change-log=db/inventory.xml
quarkus.liquibase.inventory.migrate-at-start=true
```

But something like this doesn't work in the YAML version

```
"%test":
  quarkus:
    log:
      level: INFO
    datasource:
      devservices:
        enabled: true
    liquibase:
      change-log: "db/changeLog.xml"
      users:
        change-log: "db/users.xml"
```

Isn't it possible ?

Would be great if we could get more YAML examples in the docs :(

Comment: I looked through the documentation for using multiple data sources on the Quarkus site and I see their example uses PostgreSQL.  That info is here for reference: https://quarkus.io/guides/liquibase#multiple-datasources 

Does it give you a specific error when you're saying it doesn't work?

Comment: The two files are not exactly the same: does removing `"%test"` from YAML (or add `%test%` too first file) make the app to work correctly?

Comment: No, running it out of the tests doesn't work either